# Mensagem de erro ao colocar tradução no CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, i18n, internacionalização

Alguém sabe como resolver isso:

> An Error Was Encountered: Unable to load the requested language file: language/portuguese-brazilian/form_validation_lang.php

Segui o seguintes passos para a inclusão da tradução:

1. `application -> language ->` e coloquei a pasta portuguese-brazilian aqui
2. `application -> config -> $config['language']    = 'portuguese-brazilian';` (depois de apagar o english).

> obs.: o arquivo form_validation_lang.php está na pasta `portuguese-brazilian`.

Comment: dentro da pasta `portuguese-brazilian` tem alguma `pt_br ou pt-br`?

Comment: Não tem, @RafaelAcioly, tem só a english.

Comment: você esta usando o CI 2 ou 3?

Comment: CI 3, @RafaelAcioly.

Answer (score 2):

Passei pela mesma situação resolvi dando permissão para o diretorio *language*

```
$ chmod -R 775 language
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu procedimento está correto. No meu caso o zip portugueses-br que eu baixei estava gerando uma estrutura de pastas a partir do application. É só entrar na pasta que você criou e ver se lá dentro tem os arquivos PHP ou se o zip gerou a estrutura de pastas.